# MVC generating a dynamic route when storing session state in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, session

I just modified my web.config to store session state in SQL server and now the application is adding an additional dynamic route parameter to all my requests.  The route parameter looks like (S(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)).  What is this, as it now affects all of my ajax requests that do not account for this dynamically generated route?

Thanks,
Collin

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx. Look at the Cookieless State, you probably want to set it to false.

Comment: For ASP.NET Core the following is a nice tutorial on Session storage: http://andrewlock.net/an-introduction-to-session-storage-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: Thanks guys,  the answer was setting cookieless to false

Answer (score 0):

Needed to set Cookieless to false